# Order of Faithful Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to solve this problem: If a group $G$ acts faithfully on a set $X$ and $|X| = n,$ then $|G|$ divides $n!$.

I tried using the fact that every group of order $k$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $S_k$, but I wasn't able to make any progress on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument goes as follows:

A group action of $G$ on $X$ is an homomorphism of $G$ into $S_X$, the group of permutations of $X$. The action is faithful iff this homomorphism is injective. Thus if the action is faithful, $G$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $S_n$. Therefore $|G|$ divides $n!$.

Think about each step carefully.